# How to create interface from typeof?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I dynamically go "backwards" from object to interface?

```
const o = {
  a: 1,
  b: "hi"
}

interface i = typeof o; // how to write this?
```

The result should be equivalent to:

```
interface i {
  a: number,
  b: string
}
```

Comment: I hate to ask the annoying question, because you have a reason, but I gotta ask, in a prototypal language that Typescript is a superset of (Javascript), why are you trying to do this? Just define const o: i

Comment: TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, so "dynamically" doesn't really make sense. What's the underlying requirement here?

Comment: Just use `type` instead of `interface`: `type i = typeof o`;

Comment: No easy way to do this I suspect, especially concerning objects with nested objects.

Answer (score 11):

You can't directly create an interface, but you can create a type alias, which you can in most casses be used the same as an interface (ie. You can extend a new interface from it or implement it in a class

```
const o = {
a: 1,
b: "hi"
}

type i = typeof o; 
interface ii extends i { }
class ci implements i {
    a = 1;
    b = ''
}
```

Comment: but what about if we don't need to add extra properties like a or b?